# Passing values from action class to model class in symfony

Tags: symfony1

I have a action class for saving some data to a database.In action class iam getting a id through url.I have to save the id in table.

I am getting the id by $request->getParameter('id')

I used this code for saving

$this->form->bind($request->getParameter('question_answers'));
if ($this->form->isValid())
{
        $this->form->save();
    $this->redirect('@homepage');
}

in model class i used a override save method to save extra field

public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null)
{
if ($this->isNew())
{

```
$now=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
$this->setPostedAt($now);
```

}
    return parent::save($conn);
so i want to get the id value here .
So how can i pass id value from action class to model class

is any-other way to save the id in action class itself
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is that id about? is it the id of the object from the DB table?

Comment: No it is a number getting from url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

$this->form->getObject()->setQuestionId($request->getParameter('id'));
$this->form->save();

QuestionId=field name

$request->getParameter('id')= is the default value

Answer (score 0):

Most probably not the best solution but you can save that id value in a session variable and use it later anywhere you need. something like:

```
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('id', $request->getParameter('id')); // in action class
```

and

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getAttribute('id'); // in model class
```

Comment: is it possible to save in the action class itself like
$this->form->question_id=2;

Comment: I was actually going to offer you the same but I do not have my working environment in front of me so I could not test before I answer but you can try out that also. Sounds possible to me.

Comment: Just use 

$this->form->getObject()->setQuestionId($request->getParameter('id'));
$this->form->save();

QuestionId=field name

$request->getParameter('id')= is the default value

Answer (score 0):

If your model has a field for this ID already (eg in your example posted_id), then you can do one of 2 things:

1: Pass the ID to your form when you create it, as an option:

```
$this->form = new MyForm(array(), array("posted_id" => $id));
```

and then you can override your form's doSave() method to set the field:

```
// ...
$this->getObject()->posted_id = $this->getOption("posted_id");
// ...
```

or similar

2: Add a widget to your form in the configure() method with a corresponding validator, and pass in the ID when you get the values from the request:

```
$values = $request->getParameter('question_answers');
$values["posted_id"] = $request->getParameter("id");
$this->form->bind($values);
```

If you're rendering your form manually, just don't render this new field in your view template.

Either way, saving the model as a result of the form saving it will include this new field I believe. The second one is from memory, but it should technically work... :-)

Comment: Actually the id is getting from the url i want to just add on the table

Answer (score 0):

Best practice I'm using consists of 2 steps:

1. Pass additional data to forms' options (2nd constructor's parameter or just `$form->setOption('name', 'value')`);
2. override protected method `doUpdateObject` in way like this:

   ```
   protected function doUpdateObject($values)
   {
     $this->getObject()->setFoo($this->getOption('foo'));
     parent::doUpdateObject($values);
   }
   ```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You could use (sfUser)->setFlash and (sfUser)->getFlash instead of setAttribute, it's more secure...