# getting posted values in model class in symfony

Tags: symfony1

How i can pass values from action class to model class

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not using forms (and therefore you haven't gone through the tutorial on the Symfony site...!), then something like the following would work in your action:

```
public function executeMyAction(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  if ($request->isMethod("post"))
  {
    $postVar1 = $request->getParameter("postVar1");
    $postVar2 = $request->getParameter("postVar2");

    $model = new MyModel();
    $model->field1 = $postVar1;
    $model->field2 = $postVar2;
    $model->save();
  }
}
```

Obviously the above includes no data sanitization at all or validation; you'd need to implement this yourself.  Use the form framework if possible though; all the validation is handled nicely for you with this, and you can simply pass your request parameters to the form and let it get on with it :-)

Comment: Thanks but iam using form for saving data. 

$this->form->bind($request->getParameter('question_answers'));
   if ($this->form->isValid())
   {  
    $this->form->question_id=2;
    $this->form->save();
    $this->redirect('@homepage');
   }
but i want to add an exta field that is not entering on the form

Comment: In that case, I'd pass in the id as an option to the form and override in your form's doSave().  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2461585/passing-values-from-action-class-to-model-class-in-symfony/2461991#2461991